# Documents required by UK citizens traveling to the US by train

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I am a British citizen and I will be traveling from the UK to Toronto and staying in Canada for couple of weeks and then traveling by train from Montreal to New York where I will be staying for 4 days then flying back from New York to the UK. Please advise as to what documents I will need? Thanks Ann

Comment: passport, eta, esta but this is 100% to be a duplicate

Comment: Same documents you would need for a visa or entering the USA by air. Nothing different about entering by train.

Comment: @chx ESTA only applies to arrivals by air, not land border crossings. https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country%2C-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico%2C